# How can i get data from file path using tkinter and PdFileReader

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I use this method :

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = Tk()

def browsefunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)

browsebutton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=browsefunc)
browsebutton.pack()

pathlabel = Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()

def get_info(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        info = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
        number_of_pages = pdf.getNumPages()

    print(info)

    author = info.author
    creator = info.creator
    producer = info.producer
    subject = info.subject
    title = info.title


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = pathlabel.pack()
    get_info(path)

mainloop()
```

However, i get the following error:

> TypeError: invalid file: None

How can i get the file from `pathlabel`?

Is it possible to open the file from file path?

Comment: I don't think you have a clear understanding of what `if __name__ == '__main__':` is for and what you are doing with  `path = pathlabel.pack()`. Maybe you mean `path = pathlabel["text"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple problems here.

Delete this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = pathlabel.pack()
    get_info(path)
```

what this is doing is making `path` = to the result of `pathlabel.pack()`. That result will always be `None` as `pack()` is always going to return `None`. Then you are passing `None` to the `get_info()` function.

Instead lets call `get_info` from your `brousefunc()` functions.

Change `brousefunc()` to this:

```
def browsefunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)
    get_info(filename)
```

This will update your label and then also send the correct file path to the `get_info` function.

If you still wish to use the label's text for the file path you can do `path = pathlabel["text"]` as this will assign the value of the text to the path.

I can't test `PyPDF2` on my end but the below should work for you.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()


def get_info(path):

    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        info = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
        number_of_pages = pdf.getNumPages()

    author = info.author
    creator = info.creator
    producer = info.producer
    subject = info.subject
    title = info.title

    print(number_of_pages, author, creator, producer, subject, title)


def browsefunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)
    get_info(filename)


browsebutton = tk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=browsefunc)
browsebutton.pack()

pathlabel = tk.Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

To address your question in the comments here is an example that displays in the GUI.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


root = tk.Tk()

label_list = []

def get_info(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        info = pdf.getDocumentInfo()

        label_list[0].config(text=pdf.getNumPages())
        label_list[1].config(text=info.author)
        label_list[2].config(text=info.creator)
        label_list[3].config(text=info.producer)
        label_list[4].config(text=info.subject)
        label_list[5].config(text=info.title)

def browsefunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)
    get_info(filename)

browsebutton = tk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=browsefunc)
browsebutton.pack()

pathlabel = tk.Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()

for i in range(6):
    label_list.append(tk.Label(root, text=""))
    label_list[i].pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @CodeID Glad to help. Please select the check mark next to my answer to show your problem has been resolved.

Comment: is possible to view the data with GUI tkinter sir? @Mike - SMT

Comment: @CodeID sure. You just need to run a function that set some labels with the data.

Comment: @CodeID I added an example that displays in the GUI.

Comment: @CodeID sorry fixed. The label edits needed to be in the with statement and I was missing the `.config` portion. Should work now.

Comment: @CodeID you need to take the time to accept the answer you have received on your questions. I took a look at your previous question and you do not accept the answer to your problem. This is part of how the Q/A process works here. Please take the time to review your questions and accept answer that apply.

Comment: thanks you sir, i'll take the time to rivew again. thanks again @Mike - SMT

Comment: i choose the file, and the code give me the data, and when i added a new button save, which button will show me when i choose the file. and when i choose a new file again, it show me 2 save button. how can i break the save button when i choose a new file?

Comment: @CodeID That is a new problem for a new question. Please accept this answer as it has solved your problem in this question.

Comment: yes i have accept the answer before. thanks before.
and now i got a new problem, can you help me sir? please

Comment: You will need to ask a new question. That's how the Q/A work here. Even if you find a new problem after your original issue has been fixed you need to ask a new question for the new problem. So let me know when you posted your new question and I can help.

Comment: i already post a new question sir, this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638610/how-to-break-looping-in-tkinter